# Using selenium/standalone-chrome in docker-compose connecting with Python's selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I've been having trouble getting Python selenium to connect to `selenium/standalone-chrome`, and was looking for insight on how to fix my issue. I would like to avoid using `selenium/hub`, but including it does not seem to fix my issue.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  web:
    external: true

services:

  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    hostname: chrome
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
      - "4444:4444"
    privileged: true
    shm_size: 2g

  tests:
    build: ./tests
    networks:
      - web
```

And the test I'm running inside the test container. The entrypoint checks to make sure that chrome is up and running before running the scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Tests that the remote webdriver works."""
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


class LocalGoogleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def testPageTitle(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
        self.assertIn('Google', self.browser.title)


class RemoteGoogleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://chrome:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def testPageTitle(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
        self.assertIn('Google', self.browser.title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

For the test results, the `Local` test succeeds, it's only when trying to use the remote. Occasionally I will get the error `hub not found in PATH`, but that error is intermittent.

I am able to access the web interface via `http://server:444/wd/hub` and can start sessions and run scripts from there.

I believe this may be an issue related to containers not being able to reach out to each other and I have evaluated the following resources for trying to workout that issue:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-connect-to-other-containers-inside-docker-network/66512
- https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-doesnt-let-my-images-connect-with-each-other/54951

Posts I've examined which did not work:

- [Docker: using container with headless Selenium Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781266/docker-using-container-with-headless-selenium-chromedriver)
- [docker selenium/standalone-chrome unable to connect to docker web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004832/docker-selenium-standalone-chrome-unable-to-connect-to-docker-web-server)
- [Easiest way to run Selenium tests in a Docker container over Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014781/easiest-way-to-run-selenium-tests-in-a-docker-container-over-jenkins-ci)
- [Selenium webdriver.Remote driver does not work with tor proxy(webdriver.Chrome does)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159994/selenium-webdriver-remote-driver-does-not-work-with-tor-proxywebdriver-chrome-d)
- [How do I link and scale multiple docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685543/how-do-i-link-and-scale-multiple-docker-containers)
- [How to point RemoteWebDriver to one of the multiple standalone docker selenium standalone chrome browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527048/how-to-point-remotewebdriver-to-one-of-the-multiple-standalone-docker-selenium-s)

Thanks for looking!

Update: From within the tests container, I am able to `curl http://chrome:4444/wd/hub/status` to retrieve the status that the connection is up and running, and this is part of the `entryscript.sh`, so I know the containers can talk to each other in some fashion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, of al, I'd like to thank you for all this. After reaching this post it gave me the hope that I'm not the one who is trying to do such a thing.

So, the thing is I'm successfully able to run everything from docker-compose and everything executed as expected.

Got hints from your post and made a few changes and it actually worked.

Here goes the solution.

FileName: docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
    web:
      external: true
      driver:  bridge

services:
    chrome:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
        hostname: chrome
        networks:
          - web
        privileged: true
        shm_size: 2g
    framework:
        build: .
        networks:
            - web
        depends_on: 
            - chrome
```

Also, note that the grid url is `http://chrome:4444/wd/hub`
With this change in configuration, I was able to run my code successfully and I was also able to send out emails.

I hope this helps someone who is stuck with docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the solution I was struggling with the same error, but in my case the fail was that I didn't add the following lines:

```
privileged: true
shm_size: 2g
```

I will add just one "fix" if you want to call it to your solution. **As all the containers are built under the same docker-compose file you don't need to create a network, it is automatically created for all of them**.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    chrome:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
        hostname: chrome
        privileged: true
        shm_size: 2g
    framework:
        build: .
        depends_on: 
            - chrome
```

Once again. Thanks!